# iCloud doesn't allow me to backup

Tags: icloud, backup

So I want to backup my Ipod Touch 5 because I'm gonna have to exchange it for a new one and I have tons of photos and notes I would like to back up. I tried backing it up to itunes but its taking a long time and nothing seems to be moving. I deleted all my apps and all the non important photos and decided to try icloud instead. Most websites said I needed to make sure I was under my 5.0GB mark and my Ipod said I had 5.0GB available but when I try to back up it said there wasn't enough available storage. I deleted more photos but it still couldn't backup. I dont want to buy more storage or contact the Apple Support until I'm sure of what's happening..can someone please help me?

Comment: Did you look under Settings > General > Usage and see how much storage space is used on your device? Apps (the actual software download) won't count against the 5GB iCloud limit, though data in those apps will, so if you have a video editing app that is taking a large amount of space, that could cause problems. Similarly if you have a large amount of photos and videos in iMessage that would cause an issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fit within the 5GB limit for the iCloud backup, you need to have the **used** space on your device be less than 5GB. Technically, Apps don't count against this, although their documents/data does. There are other items that don't count, as well, you can read more about [iCloud backups here](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12519?viewlocale=en_US).

You stated that your iPod had 5GB available, but the space used for the backup is the 5GB that you have in iCloud, it is not on your device.

If you have more than 5GB used, as is likely given that it has told you there is not enough available storage, then you will need to either pay to add more iCloud storage, or just use iTunes for free.

If it is your first time backing up to iTunes and you have lots of data, it will likely take quite a while, so you should be patient when letting it complete that first backup.